# SSIS - Difference between merge and merge join

Tags: sql, ssis

I would like to know what the major difference between `merge` and `merge join` in `ssis` is.

Answer (score 1):

You should google this first. Anyway to answer :

Merge Join is same as JOIN in t-sql, you can choose between different types of Inner join, left outer join  and outer join
the difference is that with Merge join transformation you can support two inputs from two different data source, for example one from flat file and another from oracle DB, but with join in t-sql you can only join from one data source.

Merge Transform is not actually like join, this will merge rows like UNION. this differ from UNION ALL Transform a bit, you can see difference between merge and union transforms here:

http://sqlserversolutions.blogspot.com/2009/01/difference-between-merge-and-union-all.html

source : [microsoft technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/4c994ffa-4b96-461f-8472-0139e7f5e3b8/merge-vs-merge-join-in-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices)